# Length of shortest word accepted by exactly one of two DFAs

Tags: finite-automata

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two deterministic finite automata with $M_1$ having $n$ states, and $M_2$ having $m$ states, over the same alphabet $\Sigma$. Show that if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not equivalent, then there is some string $\omega \in \Sigma^*$ of length at most $n \times m$ that is in exclusively $M_1$ or $M_2$.

It is clear to me that since they are not equivalent, there is some string that is in exclusively $M_1$ or $M_2$. But how can we show that there is some string that does not exceed the required length?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the pumping lemma here.

Comment: A good start is constructing the product automaton.

Comment: Using cross product method?

Comment: Probably. I've never heard this term before in the context of finite automata.

Comment: Sorry, the Cartesian Product method? Isn't that used for the intersection? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780521/how-to-use-the-intersection-construction-to-form-a-dfa

Comment: The names you are using are not standard, but it is the construction which is important rather than the name used to describe it.

Comment: I would have assumed that we need to somehow leverage the pumping lemma. So, if I know that they are not equivalent, there is some string that is in one but not the other. I can then pump until that string is within $n \times m$ and it is still in say $M_1$. But I don't think this guarantees it is still not in $M_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the product automaton $M = M_1 \times M_2$, which contains $nm$ states. Since $L(M_1) \neq L(M_2)$, the automaton $M$ contains a state $(q_1,q_2)$ reachable from its initial state such that $q_1$ is an accepting state of $M_1$ and $q_2$ is not an accepting state of $M_2$, or vice versa. Since $M$ contains $nm$ states, this state is reachable from the initial state of $M$ by a path of length at most $nm-1$. This corresponds to a word of length $nm-1$ which is in $L(M_1)$ but not in $L(M_2)$, or vice versa.

Using the method of [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/89546/683), we can improve the bound to $n+m-2$. This is tight for $m=1$, as the example of $L(M_1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \Sigma^k$ and $L(M_2) = \Sigma^*$ shows.